# Is there is an event detecting inserting a value to an input directly from code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example if I have :

```
<input type="text" id="search" >
```

And I use Javascript/Jquery to set its value:

```
$('#search').val('someThing');
```

Is there is an event to detect this action like `keyup,click,input, ..`?

Comment: There's both an on `change` and on `focus` event handlers that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are inserting the value from code you can just call your method() on the line after the value is inserted from Javascript.

If I have misunderstood the question please elaborate and i'll help further :)

Comment: I know I could do that , But the problem is that there are some functions from another script are executed on specific events and I would like to execute these functions on inserting the value from the code

Comment: Sorry Jack , I don't quite understand what you mean  - are you saying that after you insert the values you would like the existing onChange() events to fire?  Can you post the actual code so I can see more of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I didn't realise that Teemu - good to know though :) - i've modified the answer. - If that is the case though then I think I understand the problem - are you saying that you want onChange() to fire when values are entered via code?  Which handlers do you need to fire? If you could post the actual input box i'm sure we can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener of `input` to detect when the value is changed.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#search');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => console.log(e.target.value));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```